# Unable to alter authorization on an mirroring endpoint to a login with a slash in the name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run the following statement to alter the authorization on an endpoint as the current login used for authorization is about to be deleted (left the company).

```
alter authorization on endpoint::Mirroring to domain\sys-admin-group
```

We use Windows authentication, so all our server logins have the backslash "\" character in it.

Here is the error I received:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '\'.
```

I have also tried to enclose the login in single quotes but received the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'domain\sys-admin-group'.
```

I can't find any useful info on the MSDN ALTER AUTHORIZATION page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359.aspx). Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try surrounding it with the quoted identifier:

```
alter authorization 
on endpoint::Mirroring 
to [domain\sys-admin-group]
```

Notice the square brackets.

Comment: Bingo! Yatsi! I usually use the square brackets for weird db or column names like 1234-abc, but didn't think it would apply here. Worked like a charm. Thanks Shark.

Comment: @JamesJiao No problem, glad to help.